# Azure Active Directory skip account selection on logout

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an ASP.Net Core application that connects to Azure Active Directory. The sign-on works great, but when signing out I want it to happen immediately without having to go through the "Pick an Account" screen in Azure AD.

I've used the sample app (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) and modified the startup method:

```cs
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
   {

                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
   }
```

I read that SaveTokens should cause id_token_hint to be set on logout (assuming this will bypass the logout screen) but that's not happening.

How do I make the application sign out immediately and not go to Azure's logout screen?

Comment: Which particular sample did you use in this repository?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck I used the aspnetcore2-2 branch (it has a single project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this behavior is no longer possible with the v2 endpoint: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/126

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure this in the *OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut*  event. Code from the sample [active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/fdb4ab530ac1830970855eb19bab4538edc3d553/Microsoft.Identity.Web/StartupHelpers.cs#L55)

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options => {
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
    {
       var user = context.HttpContext.User;

       // Avoid displaying the select account dialog
       context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = user.GetLoginHint();
       context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = user.GetDomainHint();
       await Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. I'm still being presented with the account selection screen. I did see the login_hint and domain_hint parameters in the URL however.

Comment: could you check if user.GetLoginHint() returns the correct login name

Comment: It does. I log in with my business email account and that's the one returned by GetLoginHint()

Comment: I got this working also.  Had to call services.Configure with a closure inside the ConfigureServices function to make this work.  Added that context in the edit.