# How to disable account selection while logout?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using Keycloak for the authentication. In Keycloak, I have configured Azure AD as an IDP. During the logout from my application, application make a request to Keycloak to logout, keycloak in turn redirects to logout Azure AD(logout endpoint). Everything works as expected, however Azure AD provide option to pick the account for logout.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNx1L.png)

I would like to disable the account selection, and my expectation is it should automatically pick the account and logout's automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you are using a v2.0 endpoint then you cannot disable account selection when logging out. This is based on security considerations and is by design.

similar questions, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048534/azure-active-directory-skip-account-selection-on-logout) and [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/126).

Comment: When I swap to the previous version of the endpoint, it works as expected. Do you have any idea whether it's recommended to use the older verison of endpoint? Will that be deprecated some time soon? Thanks again.